# Error with 'npm start'

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, npm-start

I'm using Node v4.2.6 and npm v3.5.2 on Ubuntu, I clone my proyect from github and install all the modules. When I do npm start its run fine, but when I try to run it again start crashing and the only way I find to make it work again is to re-clone the project.
It's a rare and dummy question i think, can someone help me? Pardon my bad english, here is the npm-debug.log error:

> 17 error Linux 4.4.0-92-generic
>
> 18 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "lite"
>
> 19 error node v4.2.6
>
> 20 error npm  v3.5.2
>
> 21 error code ELIFECYCLE
>
> 22 error firstApp-client@1.0.0 lite: `lite-server`
>
> 22 error Exit status 1
>
> 23 error Failed at the firstApp-client@1.0.0 lite script 'lite-server'.
>
> 23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>
> 23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the firstApp-client package,
>
> 23 error not with npm itself.
>
> 23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> 23 error     lite-server
>
> 23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>
> 23 error     npm bugs firstApp-client
>
> 23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> 23 error     npm owner ls firstApp-client
>
> 23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: You should include the value of `start` in your `package.json` so we can see what command `npm start` is actually running.

Comment: Just for the record, do you stop the previous start with `npm stop` in order to start the project?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, yes I stop npm before I execute it again. I will see my package.json file

Comment: @EmptyArsenal I have this line in the package.json

"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "

Your were making reference to it?

Comment: @andres I think that is the right section, but just add your package.json to your question, excluding bits that aren't important like dependencies, in a valid JSON format so we can see it nicely formatted and so that your question is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why but it seems to be that the problem was an incompatibility of the versions of nodejs.
I run:

`$ sudo npm cache clean -f`

`$ sudo npm install -g n`

`$ sudo n stable`

`$ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/<VERSION>/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs`

And all was resolve. Thanks for the comments